# Cypress wait for all ajax requests Solution for cy.wait('" ")

Tags: testing, xmlhttprequest, cypress, wait

I'm testing a heavy page with cypress, and I need to wait until there are no active XHR requests and i don't want to use cy.wait("")

====> solution
In your test make sur to use this code in your function of test

''  it(" ***************", function () {

```
  cy.route;
  cy.intercept({method: "GET",url: "",}).as("apiCheck");
     
  cy.wait("@apiCheck");


//////
//////  code 
//////

});''
```

Note  url: "" must be like this: it will take the existing url

Comment: Are you giving the answer inside the question? If so, might be better to write an answer separately.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.